# Using grep to filter rows with two or more patterns in the string in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to index all the rows that have a string beginning with either `"B-"` or `"B^"` in one of the columns. I tried a bunch of combinations, but I am suspecting it might not be working due to "-" and "^" signs being part of grep command as well.

```
dataset[grep('^(B-|B^)[^B-|B^]*$', dataset$Col1),]
```

With the above script, rows beginning with `"B^"` are not being extracted. Please suggest a smart way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the escape `\\` command in `grep`:

```
dataset[grep('^(B\\-|B\\^)[^B\\-|B\\^]*$', dataset$Col1),]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!! And thanks for inline edits too :)

Answer (score 0):

For further explanation, the `^` matches the beginning of a string as an anchor therefore you have to escape it in the middle of string. The `[]` are a character class so `[^B-|B^]*` matches any character that's not a B,-,B, or ^. They are unnecessary here.

The simplified regex is: 
`dataset[grep('^(B-|B\\^)', dataset$Col1),]`

Comment: I see your point about not needing the [ ] character class. Thank you for the insight!